# construct a loop for web scraping to extract drug information

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to extract drug information from this website: https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/abacavir.htm.

So far, i am able to extract the drug information (abacavir)for one web-page. Now, i need advice on how to construct a loop to extract all drug information i need for other drug from other web-pages in the same website (www.medindia.net). The code is as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/abacavir.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
drug = soup.find(class_='mi-container__fluid')
print(drug)

# whole page contain drug content
items = drug.find_all(class_='report-content drug-widget')
print(items)

# extract drug information from drug content into individual variable
trade_name = items[0].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
function = items[1].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
Contraindications = items[2].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
Dosage = items[3].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
how_to_use = items[4].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
warnings = items[5].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
storage = items[7].find(class_='drug-content').get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")

drug_stuff = pd.DataFrame(
        {
                'trade_name':[trade_name],
                'function': [function],
                'Contraindications': [Contraindications],
                'Dosage': [Dosage],
                'how_to_use':[how_to_use],
                'warnings':[warnings],
                'storage':[storage],

        })


print(drug_stuff)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place where people do everything for you, eh.

Comment: i identify the pattern of the url pages which is ```https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/#drugname.htm.```, but unable to figure out how to construct a for loop and using regular expression for extraction. Sorry, for not explaining early.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function!

```py
def extract_drug_info(url):
    """ Extracts drug information of a given medindia.com website. """

    # ... rest of the code you posted above here ...
    return drug_stuff
```

Then loop through some URLs:

```py
urls = ["https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/abacavir.htm", "..."]
for url in urls:
    print(extract_drug_info(url))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have create function and the for loop. However, the extracted information shown is the same when i pass different webpages into url. ```urls = ["https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/abacavir.htm", "https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/prucalopride.htm"]

Comment: Most likely because inside the `def extract_drug_info(url)` you are re-assigning the `url` variable. Make sure you don't have any `url = ` inside the function.

Comment: I get this error when trying to do requests.get(urls). ``` No connection adapters were found for '['https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/abacavir.htm', 'https://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/prucalopride.htm']'```

Comment: You need the protocol scheme of the website. That is, you need the `https://` or `http://`. Simple Google "No connection adapters were found for" and the first StackOverflow post answers your question...